# Equivalent to hover for mobile aps

Tags: css, mobile, carousel

What would be and equivalent for CSS hover, just to be used on devices that have a  touch screen, like tablet and smartphones? I am trying to show arrows on my carousel, for desktop I know I can use hover but what to use when there is no cursor to hover over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `:active` selector in combination with `:hover`.

> `:active` selector should be called after the `:hover` selector.

**Example**

```
 .button:hover, .button:active{
   background-color: red;
 }
```

Comment: I personally always stick with the `hover-focus-active` approach, since it also encapsulates `input` elements.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that by default, touch devices do not have Hover effect, or at least they "treat" it differently - like a click event.

Example: if you have a dropdown menu on Hover on desktop machines, it will automatically be a dropdown menu on click on mobile touch devices.

As for current inquiry, I can propose a workaround, to show the arrows on devices with max-width smaller than 1200px.